# Updating Wordpress Database on Customer Account Creation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm running a WooCommerce shop with multi-vendor support. Customers can checkout or message sellers without logging in (they have to enter an email address), but I want this to backdate their orders/enquiries when they create an account.

I'm using the WooCommerce function wc_update_new_customer_past_orders() and the hook woocommerce_created_customer for linking past orders with their new account which is working. But can't get this to work for the enquiries.

The code i'm using is below, works well using the wp_footer hook on page refresh, but not on woocommerce_created_customer. Any ideas?

```
    function link_past_enquiries_at_registration( ) {
      global $wp, $WCFM, $wpdb;
      $linked  = 0;
      $user_id = get_current_user_id();
      $customer  = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );
      $customer_email  = $customer->user_email;
      $enquiry_query = "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}wcfm_enquiries AS commission";
        $enquiry_query .= " WHERE 1 = 1";
        $enquiry_query .= " AND `customer_id` = 0";
        $enquiry_query .= " AND `customer_email` = '$customer_email'";
        $enquiry_query .= " ORDER BY commission.`ID` DESC";

        $wcfm_inqueries = $wpdb->get_results( $enquiry_query );

       if( !empty( $wcfm_inqueries ) ) {
        $wpdb->update( $wpdb->prefix . 'wcfm_enquiries', array('customer_id'=>$user_id), array('customer_email'=>$customer_email, 'customer_id'=>0) );
        $linked++;
      }
    }
    add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', 'link_past_enquiries_at_registration' );
```

Comment: Just a small advice: `woocommerce_created_customer` have 2 parameters that already provide you user_id and email. Just change `link_past_enquiries_at_registration()` to `link_past_enquiries_at_registration($user_id, $user_data)`. Then, you can get user email with `$user_data['user_email']` later in your function.

Comment: Have you tried to error_log() inside your function to check if it's being called?

Comment: Thanks, I'll change this to pass the parameters.

Comment: I've got this working! Thanks for your help